# I get name, surname and phone numbers from the contacts. However, I still can't figure out how to store them into a structure array

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, contacts

```
struct contactx {
  var contacts: [person]
}

struct person {
  var name: String
  var lastName: String
  var phoneNumber: String

  init(name: String, lastName: String, phoneNumber: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
  }
}
```

and here is my declaration:

```
 var persons = [person]()
```

and I'm trying to store it like that:

```
var phoneNumber = contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue ?? ""

  self.persons.append(person(name: contact.givenName, lastName: contact.familyName, phoneNumber: phoneNumber))
```

However I am not getting input properly. How should I declare and store these information?

Comment: First thing - Class, struct, and enum names should start with uppercase letters. Method, variable, and case names should start with lowercase letters. Follow these standard to make your code easier to read.

Comment: What do you mean by *"not getting input properly"*? Please [edit] your question and clarify what your actual issue is with the code you posted.